# spark cluster yarn "Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err."

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am getting the following error when I execute spark-submit with "cluster" deploy mode and "yarn" master.

I am using hadoop 3.1.1. I can provide yarn-site.xml and other details but they are mostly with default values.

```
2020-10-29 21:04:05 INFO  Client:54 - Submitting application application_1603994856896_0008 to ResourceManager
2020-10-29 21:04:05 INFO  YarnClientImpl:273 - Submitted application application_1603994856896_0008
2020-10-29 21:04:06 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:06 INFO  Client:54 -
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
         ApplicationMaster host: N/A
         ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
         queue: default
         start time: 1604005445796
         final status: UNDEFINED
         tracking URL: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8088/proxy/application_1603994856896_0008/
         user: centos
2020-10-29 21:04:07 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:08 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:09 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:10 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:11 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:12 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:13 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
2020-10-29 21:04:14 INFO  Client:54 - Application report for application_1603994856896_0008 (state: FAILED)
2020-10-29 21:04:14 INFO  Client:54 -
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: Application application_1603994856896_0008 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1603994856896_0008_000002 exited with  exitCode: 13
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-10-29 21:04:13.567]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1603994856896_0008_02_000001
Exit code: 13

[2020-10-29 21:04:13.568]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No such property [target] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-centos/nm-local-dir/usercache/centos/filecache/213/__spark_libs__1746573117963196214.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/XXX/hadoop-3.1.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Comment: Open the `tracking URL` and get the actual logs there

Comment: Can u mention your java,spark version?

Answer (score -1):

Change The Code setMaster("local") to setMaster("yarn"),If you use setMaster("local") in the code.
even when you submit using the master yarn.
the "master in the code" will overwrite the "master in the submit"
--sincerely